# Breadth First Search with cost

Tags: algorithms, reference-request, graphs, search-algorithms

Looking for some tutorials / references that discuss Breadth First Search that takes into consideration the cost of paths, but could not find much information.

Could someone refer a tutorial?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? Breadth-first search as used to find shortest paths is probably contained in every textbook on the subject.

Comment: Are the edges in the graph weighted or un weighted? What do you mean by "take into consideration the cost of paths"?

Comment: It is called [Uniform Cost Search](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~hal/courses/2009S_AI/Walkthrough/UCS/ucs.html) (example with animation) and basically the cost is for **edges** , not paths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a general point of view: there are tons, but I do sincerely recommend you the latest volume on Heuristic Search: [Heuristic Search: Theory and Applications](http://books.google.es/books?hl=es&lr=&id=3k5MVjKzBP4C&oi=fnd&pg=PP2&dq=Heuristic+Search%3a+Theory+and+Applications+Stefan+Edelkamp&ots=hDN2-fwpEx&sig=1aOebG6CCYnw4f92rtazPGMmZI4) by Stefan Edelkamp and Stefan Schroedl.

From a specific point of view: in spite of the graph being directed or not, breadth-first search taking costs into account

1. **If no heuristics are available**, then it amounts to either *Dijkstra* or *Uniform Cost Search*. An excellent discussion between these two algorithms is presented in [Felner, Ariel, "*Dijkstra's Algorithm versus Uniform Cost Search or a Case Against Dijkstra's Algorithm*", Symposium on Combinatorial Search, Barcelona (Spain), 2011](http://www.aaai.org/ocs/index.php/SOCS/SOCS11/paper/view/4017).
2. **If heuristics are available** Then there are also a number of interesting alternatives: A$^*$ is the usual one but RBFS also expands the same nodes in the same order with a linear consumption of memory. For these, I do strongly recommend the book by Stefan Edelkamp and Stefan Schroedl.

Hope this helps,